# Connect streaming points using VTK

Tags: c++, user-interface, graphics, 3d, vtk

I have a function that is called in a loop, and at each pass it gives (x,y,z) of a 3D point. I am trying to connect these points in real-time using VTK, but I am unable to get the rendering window to refresh after every frame. I see a bunch of lines if I exit the loop though.

Basically, this is what I am doing:

```
// Create a vtkPoints object to store the points in it
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> points = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyLine> polyLine = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyLine>::New();

// Create a cell array to store the lines in   
vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray> lines = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray>::New();

// Create a polydata to store everything in
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> linesPolyData = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();

// Setup actor and mapper
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
actor->SetMapper(mapper);

// Setup render window, renderer, and interactor
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer =  vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow =       vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor =   vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);

renderer->AddActor(actor);
renderWindow->Render();
renderer->Render();

int numpoints = 0;

while(some_condition)
{
  call_function(&x,&y,&z);
  double point[3] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
  point[0] = (float)x;
  point[1] = (float)y;
  point[2] = (float)z;

  numpoints++;
  points->InsertNextPoint(point);

  polyLine->GetPointIds()->SetNumberOfIds(numpoints);
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < num_points; i++)
{
    polyLine->GetPointIds()->SetId(i,i);                        
}

  lines->InsertNextCell(polyLine);

// Add the points to the dataset
linesPolyData->SetPoints(points);

// Add the lines to the dataset
linesPolyData->SetLines(lines);

#if VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5
mapper->SetInput(linesPolyData);
#else
mapper->SetInputData(linesPolyData);
#endif

linesPolyData->Modified();
linesPolyData->Update();

renderWindow->Render();
renderer->Render();

renderWindowInteractor->Enable();

check_loop_exit_condition(); 
}
```

If I do `renderer->Render()` outside the loop, I am getting all the lines (or at least I think I do). Can someone figure out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From [these docs](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkRenderer.html#adc877bbb1ff9a92e36146f7e379815d5), it seems that you shouldn't be directly calling

```
renderer->Render();
```

You should only call

```
renderWindow->Render();
```